# how can i make the compass needle head to south?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-location, cllocationmanager

I just created a compass application with the following code to get the heading, and it's working perfectly, notice that the needle rotate as the user heading :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if (newHeading.headingAccuracy >0) {
        float magnaticHead = [self magneticHeading:newHeading.magneticHeading fromOrientation:device.orientation];
        float trueHead = [self trueHeading:newHeading.trueHeading fromOrientation:device.orientation];
         my= trueHead;

        magneticHeadingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", magnaticHead];
        trueHeadingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",trueHead];
        heading = -1.0f * M_PI * newHeading.magneticHeading / 180.0f;
      arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading);

    }
```

so i want to make the needle point to a specific location with a known Longitude and Latitude form my current location. therefore i calculate the bearing between me an the known location with the following code :

```
-(CGFloat)bearing:(double)latitude1:(double)longitude1:(double)latitude2:(double)longitude2{

    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D user = [location coordinate];

    float dx = 21.422495 - user.latitude;
    float dy = 39.826201 - user.longitude;
     angle = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(dy, dx));


    // Set Latitude and Longitude

    latitude1 = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(latitude1);
    latitude2 = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(latitude2);
    // Calculate Difference

    double longitudeDifference = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(longitude2 - longitude1);
    // Returns the Sine and the Cosine of the specified angle

    double y = sin(longitudeDifference) * cos(latitude2);
    double x = cos(latitude1) * sin(latitude2) - sin(latitude1)* cos(latitude2) * cos(longitudeDifference);
    // Return Bearing
    double rTD =(RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(y, x))+360) ;
     CGFloat bearingValue = (float)((int)rTD % (int)360);


     return  bearingValue;

}
```

but when i use the returned value to rotate the needle, the needle wont rotate dynamically.

Anyone can help me to make the needle rotate and point to a specific location ???
Please Help!!

Comment: What does the needle do? Is it still pointing to the user's heading? Where is the code where you try to get the needle to rotate to the returned bearing? You need to post that.

Comment: I know that the needle still pointing to user's heading!!
by using:
arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading);

when i want to rotate the needle by using the returned value i use the bearing method:
    bearingValue = [self bearing:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude :locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude :21.422495 :39.826201];

arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(bearingValue);
but it's not Rotating,, i just can't figure that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the returned value from

```
-(CGFloat)bearing:(double)latitude1:(double)longitude1:(double)latitude2:(double)longitude2;
```

in a variable as the following :

```
degrees = [ self bearing:here.latitude :here.longitude :21.422495 :39.826201 ];
```

after that in the method :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading;
```

get the the head and make the needle rotate :

```
needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((degrees-newHeading.trueHeading) * M_PI / 180);
```

Now your needle is pointing to a particular Location.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling the method:

```
`bearingValue = [self bearing:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude :locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude :21.422495 :39.826201];`
```

You need to add it at the end of

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

to update the needle often enough.